# connect nodejs api to mariadb docker container

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

cant connect to mariadb container from nodejs. Here is my code:

```javascript
const mariadb = require("mariadb");

const connectMysql = async () => {
  try {
    const pool = mariadb.createPool({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      database: "gamifydb",
      port: "3306",
      password:"password"
    });
    let conn = await pool.getConnection();
    global.conn = conn;
    console.log("mariadb db connected")
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

module.exports = { connectMysql };
```

containers:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvwtL.png)

can you guys please help?

Comment: can you share the output of `docker inspect 31c5.....` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `localhost` to `172.17.0.1` and run again.

`172.17.0.1` is IP address of container gateway.